# Multiple ASP.NET 5 apps using DNX-watch command

Tags: asp.net-core, dnx

I was successfully able to get DNX-Watch command using ASP.NET 5 beta 8. Its great feature though my requirement is little bit more.

I have two projects ASP.NET 5 Web API project, normal Static HTML web app(like mini SPA).

What I would not achieve is running DNX-Watch command for both projects. Only one project can run at "localhost:5000" but if I want to run other project. An error is thrown "localhost:5000" already running.

What to know if DNX-watch runs against only project?

Answer (score 0):

1. Running multiple apps on the same port is not a `dnx-watch` issue. You'll get the same error if you try to start the two apps by hand too. You have to a different port for each application
2. Currently `dnx-watch` supports only one startup project per watcher instance. However, you can start multiple instances of `dnx-watch` and you can achieve the same result. I don't think we'll add multiple startup projects support because it creates some strange complications around console input/output and environment setup.

Comment: Thanks victor for good answer.. Will try multiple dnx watch instance